# Project root configuration file: NONE Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am working in building a declarative pipeline for my java project. I am facing a minor issue with the path which sonarQube is using when it is trying to commence with the scan activity. 
It shows "Project root configuration file: NONE" even when the file exists at my project root folder. 
My Jenkins is running on macOS

I tried fixing up the path, but, being a newbie to declarative pipelining, it is not working out as expected and I require fresh eyes to help me fix it.

```
sonar-scanner.properties : 
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=CICD-FOR-CCIQD
sonar.projectName=CICD-FOR-CCIQD
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=/cicdsample 

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src

#Binaries path
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Jenkinsfile
// find this file now

```
pipeline
{
agent any
stages
{
stage('BUILD') // works fine
{
steps
{
withMaven(maven : 'MAVEN_HOME')
{
sh 'mvn clean compile'
}
}
}
stage('SONAQ-QUBE-CHECK')  // FAILS HERE
{
environment 
{
scannerHome = tool 'sonarQubeScanner'
}
steps 
{
withSonarQubeEnv('iMacSonarQube')
{
sh '${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner'
}
}
}
stage("Quality Gate") { // WORKS FINE and skips the remaining steps because of FAILURE in previous stage
steps {
timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
}
}
}
stage('TEST')
{
steps
{
withMaven(maven : 'MAVEN_HOME')
{
sh 'mvn test'
realtimeJUnit('target/surefire-reports/*.xml') 
{
}
}
}
}
stage('PACKAGE')
{
steps
{
withMaven(maven : 'MAVEN_HOME')
{
sh 'mvn clean package'
}
}
}
stage('DEPLOY')
{
steps
{
withMaven(maven : 'MAVEN_HOME')
{
sh 'mvn spring-boot:run'
}
}
}
}
}
```

I am looking at getting this up and running. Any suggestions will help me fix this soon.

Comment: made the changes accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I identified the fix. The mistake i made was naming my file as **sonar-scanner.properties** instead of **sonar-project.properties**